# Is there a sufficient criterion to determine Lq convergence from Lp convergence (q>p)?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am wondering: If we have $p<q$ with $p,q \in [1, \infty)$ and a sequence $(f_n) \in L^p \cap L^q $ ,$(f_n) \rightarrow f \in L^p$ in $L^p$, what type of conditions are required to determine that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^q$?

My thought process so far: First and foremost, one needs that $f \in L^q$ as well. Otherwise convergence in $L^q$ is not possible.
As a finite measure space implies the other direction I would assume that a finite measure space is also required. Are these two assumptions already sufficient? I am quite sure they arent, but I cannot come up with a counter example. I also tried proving that the claim is correct, but I dont see how one can approximate $|\cdot |_{L_q}$ with $|\cdot |_{L_p}$, as the first is generally bigger. Maybe it works with Holder, but I dont see how.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In case you don't know this already: If the measure space is finite, then $L^q\subset L^p$ and if $f_n\to f$ in $L^q$, then also $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$. But you want it the other way around.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But as you said, this is the wrong direction. Im looking for the other direction/ the correct assumptions to show the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

A sufficient condition would be that $(f_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $L^{q+\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$. If $(f_n)$ is merely bounded in $L^q$, then at least $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^q$.